# Deleting item from tableview from filtered data crashing

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, searchbar

I'm trying to delete a reminder from my tableview but when its been sourced from filtering through the searchbar, the regular delete works perfect when a filter isnt taking place, but when a filter is in the search bar it crashes the app.

Heres the code;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var updatedArray = [Reminder]()

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if filtered == false {
            reminders.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableReminders.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            convertAndSaveInDDPath(array: reminders)
        }
        if filtered == true {
            updatedArray = reminders.filter{ $0.reminderName != filterData[indexPath.row].reminderName}
            print(updatedArray)
            reminders = updatedArray
            tableReminders.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableReminders.reloadData()
            //convertAndSaveInDDPath(array: reminders)

        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT (NEW CODE):

```
  public struct Reminder {
    var reminderName : String
    var reminderPriority : String
    var reminderDate : Date
    var reminderStatus : String
    var reminderSavedTime : Date
}

var reminders : [Reminder] = []

var filtered : Bool = false



public  func getFilePath(fileName:String) -> String {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(fileName)?.path
    return filePath!
}

public func convertAndSaveInDDPath (array:[Reminder]) {
    let objCArray = NSMutableArray()
    for obj in array {

        // we have to do something like this as we can't store struct objects directly in NSMutableArray
        let dict = NSDictionary(objects: [obj.reminderName ,obj.reminderPriority, obj.reminderDate, obj.reminderStatus, obj.reminderSavedTime ], forKeys: ["reminderName" as NSCopying,"reminderPriority" as NSCopying, "reminderDate" as NSCopying, "reminderStatus" as NSCopying, "reminderSavedTime" as NSCopying])
        objCArray.add(dict)
    }

    // this line will save the array in document directory path.
    objCArray.write(toFile: getFilePath(fileName: "remindersArray"), atomically: true)
}

public func getArray() -> [Reminder]? {
    var remindersArray = [Reminder]()
    if let _ = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: getFilePath(fileName: "remindersArray")) {
        let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: getFilePath(fileName: "remindersArray"))
        for (_,userObj) in array!.enumerated() {
            let reminderDict = userObj as! NSDictionary
            let reminder = Reminder(reminderName: (reminderDict.value(forKey: "reminderName") as? String)!, reminderPriority: (reminderDict.value(forKey: "reminderPriority") as? String)!, reminderDate: (reminderDict.value(forKey: "reminderDate") as? Date)!, reminderStatus: (reminderDict.value(forKey: "reminderStatus") as? String)!, reminderSavedTime: (reminderDict.value(forKey: "reminderSavedTime") as? Date)!)
            remindersArray.append(reminder)

        }
        return remindersArray
    }
    return nil
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // Reminder Section
            return filteredReminder.count
    }

    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var filterData = [Reminder]()
    var originalReminder = [Reminder]()  // original data array.
    var filteredReminder = [Reminder]()  // data that used to show in tableview.


    var sortedAZState : Bool = false
    var sortedTimeState : Bool = false
    var sortedPrioState : Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var tableReminders: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeSortBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sortBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var prioritySortBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func BtnSort(_ sender: Any) {
        sortList(sender: sortBtn) // sorts by a-z through the sort function
    }

    @IBAction func btnSortTime(_ sender: Any) {
        sortList(sender: timeSortBtn)
    }

    @IBAction func btnSortPriority(_ sender: Any) {
        sortList(sender: prioritySortBtn)
    }


    func sortList(sender: UIButton) { // should probably be called sort and not filter


        if sender.tag == 1 && sortedAZState == false {
            reminders.sort() { $0.reminderName < $1.reminderName } // sort the reminder by name
            tableReminders.reloadData(); // notify the table view the data has changed
            print("sender.tag 1")
            sortedAZState = true
        }

        else if sender.tag == 1 && sortedAZState == true {
            reminders.sort() { $0.reminderName > $1.reminderName } // sort the reminder by name
            tableReminders.reloadData(); // notify the table view the data has changed
            print("sender.tag 1")
            sortedAZState = false
        }

        else if sender.tag ==  2 && sortedTimeState == false {
            reminders.sort { $0.reminderSavedTime.compare($1.reminderSavedTime) == .orderedAscending }
            tableReminders.reloadData();
            print("sender.tag 2")
            sortedTimeState = true
        }

        else if sender.tag ==  2 && sortedTimeState == true {
            reminders.sort { $0.reminderSavedTime.compare($1.reminderSavedTime) == .orderedDescending }
            tableReminders.reloadData();
            print("sender.tag 2")
            sortedTimeState = false
        }

        else if sender.tag == 3 && sortedPrioState == false {
            reminders.sort() { $0.reminderPriority.count < $1.reminderPriority.count } // sort the reminder by priority
            tableReminders.reloadData(); // notify the table view the data has changed
            print("sender.tag 3")
            sortedPrioState = true
        }

        else if sender.tag == 3 && sortedPrioState == true {
            reminders.sort() { $0.reminderPriority.count > $1.reminderPriority.count } // sort the reminder by priority
            tableReminders.reloadData(); // notify the table view the data has changed
            print("sender.tag 3")
            sortedPrioState = false
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Create an object of the dynamic cell "plainCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReminderTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ReminderTableViewCell
        // Depending on the section, fill the textLabel with the relevant text
        // Reminder Section


        cell.reminderLabel.text = filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderName

        if filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderPriority == "!" {
            let yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "lowpriority")!
            cell.priorityImage.image = yourImage
        }

        else if filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderPriority == "!!" {
            let yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "mediumpriority")!
            cell.priorityImage.image = yourImage
        }

        else if filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderPriority == "!!!" {
            let yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "highpriority")!
            cell.priorityImage.image = yourImage
        }

        /* I DON'T KNOW WHAT THIS COMPLETION FOR, HOPE IT IS WORKING A/C TO YOUR NEED.  */

        //            cell.completeButtonAction = { [unowned self] in
        //                let reminderCall = reminders[indexPath.row].reminderName
        //                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Complete!", message: "You have completed \(reminderCall).", preferredStyle: .alert)
        //                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        //                alert.addAction(okAction)
        //
        //                reminders.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        //                self.tableReminders.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        //                convertAndSaveInDDPath(array: reminders)
        //
        //                print("reminder deleted")
        //
        //                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //            }
        //


        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        print(reminders[indexPath.row].reminderName)

        let selectedReminder = reminders[indexPath.row].reminderName
        let destinationVC = EditReminderViewController()
        destinationVC.reminderPassed = selectedReminder

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "editSegue", sender: indexPath)
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            filteredReminder.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableReminders.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            print(filteredReminder)
            convertAndSaveInDDPath(array: filteredReminder) // UNCOMMENT THIS

        }
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)  {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

      // var decapValue = searchBar.text?.lowercased()

       // print(decapValue!)
       // print(LinearSearch(searchText: decapValue!, array: reminders))

        if searchBar.text != "" {
            self.filteredReminder = originalReminder.filter({ reminder -> Bool in
                return reminder.reminderName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            })
        }
        else {
            self.filteredReminder = self.originalReminder
        }
        tableReminders.reloadData()

       // print(filterData)



    }
    /*
    func LinearSearch(searchText: String, array: [Reminder]) -> Bool { // search function to return a true or a false bool (contains two parameneters, search value and array
        for i in reminders {                                      // cycles through each element in the array
            if i.reminderName.lowercased().contains(searchText)  {                               // if element = search (return true)
            filterData.append(i)
            print(filterData)
                return true
            }
        }


        return false                                            // returns false if no element comes back to equal the searchValue
    }
*/

    @IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addSegue", sender: (Any).self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()         // example cell
      // reminders.append(Reminder(reminderName: "HOMEWORK", reminderPriority: "LOW", reminderDate: "4324", reminderStatus: "INCOMPLETE"))

        tableReminders.dataSource = self
        tableReminders.delegate = self

        searchBar.delegate = self

        tableReminders.reloadData()

        // print file path of array saved
        // print(getFilePath(fileName: "remindersArray"))

       let reminderRetrievedArray = getArray()
         reminders = reminderRetrievedArray!
        originalReminder = reminders
        gfilteredReminder = reminders

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

I didn't know which code you were after so there is all of it. But yes you are correct, it deletes one at a time, but it is saving an empty array to be loaded for next open.

Comment: In condition `if filtered == true`, this line is wrong ->  `tableReminders.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`. Remove this and try.

Comment: @dahiya_boy when I do that, it does not crash and yes it does remove it from the array but it remains in the tableview until I touch the searchbar again if that makes any sense, I want the table view to not show the deleted value, even before i touch the search bar

Comment: Remember when you do `deleteRow` or `insertRow`, you need to perform same action on your datasource also. In your  `filtered == true` you are creating new dataSource which changes the reference of object. From dev point of view, you see values but machine check address which is changed. And in `filtered == false` you are doing perfect that's why it is working and `true` is not.

Comment: @dahiya_boy how would I go about doing this in the filtered part?

Comment: It depends on your functionality. How it work for user? What is the user interaction?

Comment: Its simply just a swipe to delete on a cell. I want the user to be able to swipe and delete from a search query which does work, but soon as the delete button is hit the no longer existent cell remains in the view until the search bar is interacted with again.

Comment: Add cellforRow , numberOfRows delegate code work.

Comment: I already have these, I edited it into my original post, please take a look.

Comment: Add `numberOfRowsInSection` also.

Comment: Refer to edit 2, I missed this in my first edit, sorry.

Comment: Use `removeAll(where:)` instead of `filter` to keep the datasource reference

Answer (score 1):

Here are the changes to make your code work perfect, clean, understandable and working. If you have any doubt then write comment and if there is any wrong in answer then update the answer.

---

1. You don not need to maintain flag **filtered**. I am assuming you have two array

   ```
   var originalReminder = [Reminder]()  // original data array.
   var filteredReminder = [Reminder]()  // data that used to show in tableview.
   ```
2. In `ViewDidLoad` , set right data in `originalReminder` and if you wanted to show all the original data in table then assign same data in `filteredReminder` also.
3. Now we will manage the tableview with 1 array i.e. `filteredReminder` and if searchbar text is empty the then we will assign orignal array to filtered array. So your `searchbar textDidChange` look like this.

   ```
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

       if searchBar.text != "" {
           self.filteredReminder = originalReminder.filter({ reminder -> Bool in
               return reminder.reminderName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
           })
                   }
       else {
           self.filteredReminder = self.originalReminder
       }
       tableReminders.reloadData()
   }
   ```
4. You can remove redundant code from `cellForRow` like below

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return filteredReminder.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       // Create an object of the dynamic cell "plainCell"
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReminderTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ReminderTableViewCell
       // Depending on the section, fill the textLabel with the relevant text
       // Reminder Section


       cell.reminderLabel.text = filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderName

       if filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderPriority == "!" {
           let yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "lowpriority")!
           cell.priorityImage.image = yourImage
       }

       else if filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderPriority == "!!" {
           let yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "mediumpriority")!
           cell.priorityImage.image = yourImage
       }

       else if filteredReminder[indexPath.row].reminderPriority == "!!!" {
           let yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "highpriority")!
           cell.priorityImage.image = yourImage
       }

       /* I DON'T KNOW WHAT THIS COMPLETION FOR, HOPE IT IS WORKING A/C TO YOUR NEED.  */

       //            cell.completeButtonAction = { [unowned self] in
       //                let reminderCall = reminders[indexPath.row].reminderName
       //                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Complete!", message: "You have completed \(reminderCall).", preferredStyle: .alert)
       //                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
       //                alert.addAction(okAction)
       //
       //                reminders.remove(at: indexPath.row)
       //                self.tableReminders.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
       //                convertAndSaveInDDPath(array: reminders)
       //
       //                print("reminder deleted")
       //
       //                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
       //            }
       //


       return cell

   }
   ```
5. To delete the cell, now need to do this only.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       if editingStyle == .delete {

               filteredReminder.remove(at: indexPath.row)
               tableReminders.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
              //                convertAndSaveInDDPath(array: filteredReminder) // UNCOMMENT THIS

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This has fixed exactly what I wanted, but now when I delete a reminder now, it is setting the filtered array to empty and saves as so, so when the new program opens it is loading an empty array.

Comment: `so when the new program opens it is loading an empty array.` I didnt understand what you talking about??

Comment: Yes it loads an empty array because I believe when it is deleting after a search has been conducted, the array is filtered to nothing so it saves an empty array.

Comment: @sav Only one value will be deleted at a time. So there might be another issue. Remove old code from question and upload new code.